# Django validate elements of M2M relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models like this:

```
class Algorithm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    algorithm_type = models.CharField()

class Archive(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    algorithms = models.ManyToManyField(Algorithm)
```

I have the requirement that all Algorithms connected to an Archive must have the same algorithm_type.

So if an Algorithm is added to an Archive that has a different type than existing ones, I want to raise an Exception.

Where should I put such a check?